# Escape characters in SQLite query

Tags: android, sqlite

I want to select some data from the sqllite Db. Now I face a problem.
I have give a raw query as follows:

```
String MY_QUERY0 = "select * from logs where log_name=\""+log_name.replace("'","\'")+"\"";
```

this can help me to avoid the application from being crashing when a data like

> Names's

is pulled from the Db. 
But now I have to solve the same case with double quotes. data like

> "Data"

can any one help..
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Does Android's SQLite API support query parameters? If so, you should use them instead of building SQL on the fly.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can make use of the rawQuery:

> ```
> q = "select * from logs where log_name = ?";
> database.rawQuery(q, new String[] { log_name});
> ```

This not only solves your quotes problem but its also much more secure because it prevents SQL Injection.